# Prove that there are as many quadratic residues mod p as there are quadratic non-residues mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I have found various proofs of this question usig primitive roots, but I want to prove it without using primitive roots!

Here is my question again:

Let $p$ be prime. Prove that there are the same number of quadratic residues modulo p as there are non-residues. Clearly state where you have used that $p$ is prime.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hint: $x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ has exactly two solutions for each non-zero $a$.

Comment: you should add the hypothesis of non-zero quadratic residues, otherwise you have $(p+1)/2$ residues and $(p-1)/2$ non-residues.

Comment: Would it be enough to say this?: Define a funtion $f: R -> R$ by $f(x)\equiv x^2\bmod p$ . Now $R$ is both the domain and codomain of $f$. Also, $Q$= image($f$) and $N$ = $R$/image($f$). Then we observe that each element of image($f$) is at the end of exactly two arrows of the mapping. Hence, |image($f$)| = $\frac{1}{2}$|$R$|, so |$Q$| = \frac{1}{2} |$R$|. But also, |$N$| = |$R$| - |$Q$| = \frac{1}{2} |$R$| = |$Q$|. We can see that the observation is true because if a is in the image($f$) then there exists x in $R$ such that $x^2\equiv a\bmod p$ as well as $(-x)^2\equiv a\bmod p$.

Comment: So $a$ is at the end of at least 2 arrows of the mapping. Also, Lagrange's theorem says that there are exactly 2 solutions so $a$ is at the end of exactly 2 arrows of the mapping.

Comment: $$x^2\equiv a^2\pmod{p}\iff p\mid x^2-a^2=(x+a)(x-a)$$

$p$ is prime, so by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma):

$$\iff x\equiv \pm a\pmod{p}$$

Therefore $(\pm 1)^2$, $(\pm 2)^2$, $((p-1)/2)^2$ are all the quadratic residues.

Answer (score 1):

We are considering only invertible elements, and we have to assume $p>2$ since for $p=2$ the statament is false because there is just one invertible element. $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p \iff x \equiv y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv -y \pmod p$ because $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field and thus an integral domain. So you reach exactly two times the same quadratic residue using the $p-1$ invertible elements. Thus you get exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ different values. The remaining are $(p-1) - \frac{p-1}{2}=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Comment: How do you do this with $p=2$ ?

Comment: in that case there is just one inberible element thud the statement is of course false!

Comment: You could add this to your answer: we have to assume that $p>2$.

Comment: I apologise, I should have said $p$ is an odd prime....that is what we usually work with :)